# Ruby url to html link conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm building a simple chat app with Rails. when a user types in a url, I want it to be output as an html link (ie, "url").

I was wondering if there is any library or well known way to do this in Ruby. If not, I've got some decent regex sample code to work with...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the [auto_link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M001752) helper method provided by Rails. This turns all URLs and email addresses into clickable links (html anchor tags). Here's a code sample from the docs.

```
auto_link("Go to http://www.rubyonrails.org and say hello to david@loudthinking.com")
# => "Go to <a href=\"http://www.rubyonrails.org\">http://www.rubyonrails.org</a> and
#     say hello to <a href=\"mailto:david@loudthinking.com\">david@loudthinking.com</a>"
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! so I could loop through every word in the message, if it passes the regex url test, render it as a link. I guess I'll have to figure out how to do this in the controller and not in a view. thanks again.

Comment: No need to loop through every word, If you pass the entire string to auto_link it should just link the urls and emails. Also, if you need to call this method outside of the view, check out this episode: http://railscasts.com/episodes/132-helpers-outside-views

Comment: This method has been removed from rails 3.1 but is available as a standalone gem 'rails_autolink' you could also look at the 'rinku' gem that offers performance benefits over the rails implementation.

Comment: Removed from Rails 3.1 and packaged into [auto_link](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink) gem